# Pig Apache Local cannot run any trial in Unix Shell

Tags: ubuntu, apache-pig

I've set up both the `JAVA_HOME` and the `PIG_HOME`.

When I try `$pig - x - local trial.pig`,the feedback is as follows:

> 2013-04-21 04:01:30,833 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig
>   version 0.11.1 (r1459641) compiled Mar 22 2013, 02:13:53
>
> 2013-04-21 04:01:30,834 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging
>   error messages to: /home/tony/pig_1366531290745.log
>
> 2013-04-21 04:01:32,091 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2997:
>   Encountered IOException. File x does not exist. Details at logfile:
>   /home/tony/pig_1366531290745.log

Then I try `$pig - x - local`, the result is almost the same.

What is wrong with this? Installation of Java? Installation of Pig? Or did I export the wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
pig -x local trial.pig
```

Reference: [Getting started guide](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/start.html#run)

Comment: Sorry. i typed a redundant dash. but after i tried yours, i think it turns out to be error 2999 then.